# Scrape HTML table data with BeautifulSoup4

Tags: html, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the "Market Cap" data from the summary page on Yahoo Finance.

The html data from Chrome inspect tool looks as follows:
[image]

My code is:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

sp500short = ['a', 'aa', 'aapl', 'abbv', 'abc', 'abt', 'aci', 'acn', 'act', 'adbe', 'adi', 'adm', 'adp']
dowJones = ['mmm', 'axp', 'aapl', 'ba', 'cat', 'cvx', 'csco', 'ko', 'dd', 'xom', 'ge', 'gs', 'hd', 'intc', 'ibm', 'jpm', 'jnj', 'mcd', 'mrk', 'msft', 'nke', 'pfe', 'pg', 'trv', 'utx', 'unh', 'vz', 'v', 'wmt', 'dis']


def stockScreener():

    for ticker in sp500short:
        searchSummary = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s="+ticker
        summary = urlopen(searchSummary)
        summaryHtml = summary.read()
        summarySoup = BeautifulSoup(summaryHtml, "html.parser")

        try:
            marketCap = summarySoup.find("th scope", text="Market Cap:").find_next_sibling("td").text

        except:
            marketCap = "There is no data for this company" 

        if marketCap == "There is no data for this company":
            print(ticker+" "+marketCap)            
        else:
            output = marketCap[:-1]
            print(ticker + str(output))

stockScreener()
```

What is wrong with my `.find()` call ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're so close - you just need to delete `scope` from the line:

```
marketCap = summarySoup.find("th scope", text="Market Cap:").find_next_sibling("td").text
```

It should look like this:

```
marketCap = summarySoup.find("th", text="Market Cap:").find_next_sibling("td").text
```

`scope` is an attribute of the `<td>` tag that you're trying to get, not part of the tag itself